# How to make batch file sequentially name itself if its previous name exists

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a little program to take and save user input so I can reference it for changes to inventory. It saves the name as Asset_Change. How do i make it where it will create a new file name if the previous one exists, so the next time the program is run, the output file would be changed to Asset_Change_1, or something along those lines.

```
@echo off
set Output="T:\Helpdesk\Documentation\HDI - Help Desk Inventory\Assets to File into 1213"

set /p Date_Sent=Date Sent: 
set /p Item=Item: 
set /p Model_Number=Model Number: 
set /p Serial_Number=Serial Number: 
set /p Item_Location=Inventory Location: 
set /p Details=Details: 
set /p RMA=RMA Number: 
set /p Repair_Cost=Repair Cost: 
set /p Shipping_Cost=Shipping Cost: 
set /p Date_Received=Date Received: 

echo Date Sent: %Date_Sent% >> %Output%\Asset_Change.txt
echo Item: %Item% >> %Output%\Asset_Change.txt
echo Model Number: %Model_Number% >> %Output%\Asset_Change.txt
echo Serial Number: %Serial_Number% >> %Output%\Asset_Change.txt
echo Item Location: %Item_Location% >> %Output%\Asset_Change.txt
echo Details: %Details% >> %Output%\Asset_Change.txt
echo RMA: %RMA% >> %Output%\Asset_Change.txt
echo Repair Cost: %Repair_Cost% >> %Output%\Asset_Change.txt
echo Shipping Cost: %Shipping_Cost% >> %Output%\Asset_Change.txt
echo Date Received: %Date_Received% >> %Output%\Asset_Change.txt

echo Thank you. This will now close.
pause
```

Every time the program is run, it currently adds the changes into the current Asset_Change.txt file. I'm basically looking to have it create a whole new file every time it is run.

Comment: The `IF` command has an `EXIST` option which lets you check if a file already exists.  You can use that to increment a number and loop back until the file does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple solution to number up a file.  The only drawback to this code is if someone deletes file 2 and File 1 and File 3 exists it will recreate file 2.  I am not sure why you are not choosing to use a date and time stamp with the file name.

```
@echo off
set "Output=T:\Helpdesk\Documentation\HDI - Help Desk Inventory\Assets to File into 1213"

set /p Date_Sent=Date Sent: 
set /p Item=Item: 
set /p Model_Number=Model Number: 
set /p Serial_Number=Serial Number: 
set /p Item_Location=Inventory Location: 
set /p Details=Details: 
set /p RMA=RMA Number: 
set /p Repair_Cost=Repair Cost: 
set /p Shipping_Cost=Shipping Cost: 
set /p Date_Received=Date Received: 

SET "num="
set "us="

:loop
IF EXIST "Asset_Change%us%%num%.txt" (
    set /A "num+=1"
    set "us=_"
    goto loop
)
set "file=Asset_Change%us%%num%.txt"

(
echo Date Sent: %Date_Sent%
echo Item: %Item%
echo Model Number: %Model_Number%
echo Serial Number: %Serial_Number%
echo Item Location: %Item_Location%
echo Details: %Details%
echo RMA: %RMA%
echo Repair Cost: %Repair_Cost%
echo Shipping Cost: %Shipping_Cost%
echo Date Received: %Date_Received%
)>>"%Output%\%file%"

echo Thank you. This will now close.
pause
```

Comment: I know only the bare basics with batch scripting, so I don't know how to do that and honestly didn't even think about doing that. But, that sounds like a much better way of doing it. I assume I can just have it throw a timestamp on the end of the filename when saving?

Comment: @ConnorVance it would be so much simpler. If your `%date%` variable does not contain slashes and uses hyphens it would be as simple as: `Asset_Change_%date%.txt`.  But most people prefer to format the date in a more usable format.

Answer (score 0):

The final code should look like:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Output=T:\Helpdesk\Documentation\HDI - Help Desk Inventory\Assets to File into 1213"

set /p Date_Sent=Date Sent: 
set /p Item=Item: 
set /p Model_Number=Model Number: 
set /p Serial_Number=Serial Number: 
set /p Item_Location=Inventory Location: 
set /p Details=Details: 
set /p RMA=RMA Number: 
set /p Repair_Cost=Repair Cost: 
set /p Shipping_Cost=Shipping Cost: 
set /p Date_Received=Date Received: 

if exist "%Output%\Asset_Change.txt" (
    set "file=Asset_Change.txt"
) else (
    set "file=Asset_Change_1.txt"
    goto :calc
)

:calc
if exist "%file%" (
    goto :out
) else (
    for /F "tokens=3 delims=_." %%A IN ("%file%") do set "num=%%A"
    set /a "num+=1"
    set "file=Asset_Change_!num!.txt"
)
goto :calc

:out
(
echo Date Sent: %Date_Sent%
echo Item: %Item%
echo Model Number: %Model_Number%
echo Serial Number: %Serial_Number%
echo Item Location: %Item_Location%
echo Details: %Details%
echo RMA: %RMA%
echo Repair Cost: %Repair_Cost%
echo Shipping Cost: %Shipping_Cost%
echo Date Received: %Date_Received%
)>>"%Output%\%file%"

echo Thank you. This will now close.
pause
```

This is the best solution I found. I know it is complicated, but I couldn't further simplify it.

Type in cmd:

- `for /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `goto /?`

for more information about the commands used.

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve. After taking the final input, it just hangs and doesn't process any further.